# How to search a file for a pattern and conditionally replace it?

Tags: perl

I've got some old PHP files that I'm trying to update to work with v7.  There are a bunch of places where the author used short open tags (ie, `<?`) and I need to change them to the normal open tags (`<?php`).  But he also sometimes used the normal open tag as well as the short echo tag (`<?=`).  So those two instances should NOT be updated.  And a single line in a file can contain more than one open tag that needs to be updated and/or should not be updated.

So to summarize, I need to search a file for `<?` and replace it with `<?php` ONLY IF it does not have either an equal sign or 'php' after it.

Some examples:

This line has two instances of `<?` that need to be replaced by `<?php`:

```
<input type="radio" name="Period" value="Month" <? if (($Period=="Month") || !isset($Period)){ ?>checked="checked" <? } ?>>
```

This line has several instances of `<?=`, none of which should be replaced (ie, this line would be left as-is):

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?s=<?=$s?>&t=<?=$t?>&order=<?=$order?>&sens=<?=$sens?>&current_page=<?=$current_page?>">
```

This line has several instances of `<?=` which should be left as-is and one instance of `<?` which should be replaced by `<?php`:

```
<a href="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?s=1&t=<?=$t?>&order=<?=$order?>&sens=<?=$sens?>&current_page=<? echo ($current_page+1)?>
```

I could crawl through the file and get the position of every `<?` and then see what the next few characters are but it seems like there would be a better way.  Is there a regex way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i -pe 's/<\?([^=p])/<?php\1/g' file.txt
```

use () to capture matched result, and \1 will be the captured value

file.txt content is:

`<input type="radio" name="Period" value="Month" <? if (($Period=="Month") || !isset($Period)){ ?>checked="checked" <? } ?>>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?s=<?=$s?>&t=<?=$t?>&order=<?=$order?>&sens=<?=$sens?>&current_page=<?=$current_page?>">
<a href="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?s=1&t=<?=$t?>&order=<?=$order?>&sens=<?=$sens?>&current_page=<? echo ($current_page+1)?>
<input type="checkbox" name="tomonth" value="true" <? if ($tomonth){ ?>checked<?}?>>`

Comment: Nice. Can you explain the code a bit so that others can learn from it or at least understand what they're doing?

Comment: @Robert -- `s/<\?[^=p]/<?php /g'`, s - for substitute, < - opens php tag, \? - ? mark protected with backslash symbol (? has special meaning in regex), [^=p] - non of the symbols in square brackets,  after second / string to substitute with <?php ', after third / -- modification flags, g - stands for globally (in this particular case it means all occurrences in the line). The file read line by line into $_ variable which is automatically printed after modification due `-p` flag, `-i` flag indicates 'make changes in place' -- make change in read file.

Comment: @PolarBear Thanks. Yes, I know this, but OP may not. I was trying to have asthman [edit] the answer and improve it. Code only answers are allowed, but an explanation always makes the answer better.

Comment: This is almost working.  I found an instance where a character is being removed/overwritten when there is no space after the ```<?``` tag:   ```<input type="checkbox" name="tomonth" value="true" <? if ($tomonth){ ?>checked<?}?>>```.  At the end of the line, the ```<?}?>``` should be ```<?php }?>``` after conversion, but it's being changed to ```<?php ?>``` instead.  The ```}``` is gone.